# How to use relative paths in general C program?

Tags: c, path

I have created a C program which I'd like to publish to Homebrew, so it needs to be able to be run from any working directory (via a symlink in the user's PATH).

The program uses relative paths (relative to the code) for file writing, and I'm not sure how to set it up so that the relative paths will work, regardless of what location the program is run from. (using absolute paths doesn't seem to be an option, since it needs to run on anyone's system).

Please could someone provide some general guidance on how to approach this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux, the file `/proc/self/exe` is a symbolic link to the actual executable running. Hence you could use that to ascertain the directory where the executable is, and work from there.

For example, this program (executable file `/home/pax/testprog`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    // Buffer should be more robust in real program but read anyway.

    char buff[1000];
    ssize_t sz = readlink("/proc/self/exe", buff, sizeof(buff));

    // Find final directory separator (from '/home/pax/testprog').

    while (sz > 0 && buff[sz-1] != '/')
        --sz;

    // Truncate string to directory name only, and print.

    buff[sz] = '\0';
    printf("[%s]\n", buff);
}
```

generates the following output:

```
[/home/pax/]
```

---

For MacOs, it's the same theory, but you may not necessarily have `procfs` available to you. On that system however, there's another way to get the path:

```
int proc_pidpath(
  int pid,              // pid of the process to know more about
  void * buffer,        // buffer to fill with the abs path
  uint32_t  buffersize  // size of the buffer
);
```

So, in order to use this, replace:

```
ssize_t sz = readlink("/proc/self/exe", buff, sizeof(buff));
```

with:

```
ssize_t sz = proc_pidpath(getpid(), buff, sizeof(buff));
```

though you'll probably also need the `libproc.h` header (`getpid` is already included as part of `unistd.h`).

Comment: That works perfectly thank you. However, there is one strange issue: although the function `readlink` is clearly defined in the included header `<unistd.h>` (since the code works), I get the following warning on compilation: `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘readlink’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @Tom, it may be hidden within `#ifdef` blocks where you have to define certain things before including the header.